# memcpy Inheritance-like structs - is it safe?

Tags: c, oop, inheritance, memcpy

I have two structs I'm working with, and they are defined nearly identical. These are defined in header files that I cannot modify.

```
typedef struct
{
    uint32_t    property1;
    uint32_t    property2;
} CarV1;

typedef struct
{
    uint32_t    property1;
    uint32_t    property2;
    /* V2 specific properties */
    uint32_t    property3;
    uint32_t    property4;
} CarV2;
```

In my code, I initialize the V2 struct at the top of my file, to cover all my bases:

```
static const carV2 my_car =  {
    .property1 =   value,
    .property2 =   value,
    /* V2 specific properties */
    .property3 =   value,
    .property4 =   value
};
```

Later, I want to retrieve the values I have initialized and copy them into the struct to be returned from a function via void pointer. I sometimes want V2 properties of the car, and sometimes V1. How can I memcpy safely without having duplicate definitions/initializations? I'm fairly new to C, and its my understanding that this is ugly and engineers to follow me in looking at this code will not approve. What's a clean way to do this?

```
int get_properties(void *returned_car){
     int version = get_version();
     switch (version){
         case V1:
         {
             CarV1 *car = returned_car;
             memcpy(car, &my_car, sizeof(CarV1)); // is this safe? What's a better way?
         }
         case V2:
         {
             CarV2 *car = returned_car;
             memcpy(car, &my_car, sizeof(CarV2));
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do note that `memcpy(&car, &my_car, sizeof(CarV1));` is wrong, it should anyway be `memcpy(car, &my_car, sizeof(CarV1));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's definitely possible to do what you're asking.

You can use a base struct member to implement inheritance, like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint32_t    property1;
    uint32_t    property2;
} CarV1;

typedef struct
{
    CarV1       base;
    /* V2 specific properties */
    uint32_t    property3;
    uint32_t    property4;
} CarV2;
```

In this case, you're eliminating the duplicate definitions. Of course, on a variable of type `CarV2*`, you can't reference the fields of the base directly - you'll have to do a small redirection, like this:

```
cv2p->base.property1 = 0;
```

To upcast to `CarV1*`, do this:

```
CarV1* cv1p = &(cv2p->base);
c1vp->property1 = 0;
```

---

You've written `memcpy(&car, &my_car, sizeof(CarV1))`. This looks like a mistake, because it's copying the data of the pointer variable (that is, the *address* of your struct, instead of the  struct itself). Since `car` is already a pointer (`CarV1*`) and I'm assuming that so is `my_car`, you probably wanted to do this instead:

```
memcpy(car, my_car, sizeof(CarV1));
```

If `my_car` is `CarV2*` and `car` is `CarV1*` (or vice versa), then **the above code is guaranteed to work by the C standard**, because the first member of a struct is always at a zero offset and, therefore, the memory layout of those two for the first `sizeof(CarV1)` bytes will be identical.

**The compiler is not allowed to align/pad that part differently** (which I assume is what you meant about optimizing), because you've explicitly declared the first part of `CarV2` to *be* a `CarV1`.

---

Since in your case you are stuck with identically defined structs that you can't change, you may find useful that the C standard defines a macro/special form called `offsetof`.

To be absolutely sure about your memory layouts, I'd advise that you put a series of checks during the initialization phase of your program that verifies whether the `offsetof(struct CarV1, property1)` is equal to `offsetof(struct CarV2, property1)` etc for all common properties:

```
void validateAlignment(void)
{
    if (offsetof(CarV1, property1) != offsetof(CarV2, property1)) exit(-1);
    if (offsetof(CarV1, property2) != offsetof(CarV2, property2)) exit(-1);
    // and so on
}
```

This will stop the program for going ahead in case the compiler has done anything creative with the padding.

It also won't slow down your program's initialization because `offsetof` is actually calculated at compile time. So, with all the optimizations in place, the `void validateAlignment(void)` function should be optimized out completely (because a static analysis would show that the exit conditions are always false).

Comment: Thanks for explaining each step of the way. I should have mentioned, I actually can't modify the header files which hold the structs. That's what makes this challenging actually. It sounds like though you think its perfectly reasonable to memcpy either `sizeof(CarV1)` or `sizeof(CarV2)` depending on which I need. That's what I thought was frowned upon.

Comment: @unexpected62 Oh, I hadn't realized that this was your main question. Yes, I believe it's reasonable to `memcpy` the identical parts between two structs (as long as these parts are in the beginning for both structs). As far as I can tell, you're not invoking any undefined behavior here, which is usually the biggest type of pitfall in C.

Comment: Is it possible that the compiler may optimize differently V1 to V2 and result in an erroneous copy at any point?

Comment: @unexpected62 I wasn't 100% sure about my suggestion with the macros and I couldn't find a link for the source I had in mind, so I removed it from my answer. (Sorry about that!) Instead, **use the method with the base struct member, since it's guaranteed to work the way you expect.** (See my edited answer.)

Comment: I really appreciate the explanation in your last bit there - `The compiler is not allowed to align/pad that part differently (which I assume is what you meant about optimizing), because you've explicitly declared the first part of CarV2 to be a CarV1.` I am going to mark this as accepted since it would work, if I could in fact change the header files. The fact that I can't leaves me hanging. Thank you.

Comment: @unexpected62 See my new edit, I've added one last thing you might find useful for your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote will almost work, except that instead of memcpy(&car, ... you should just have memcpy (car, ..., but there is no reason to use memcpy in such a case.  Rather, you should just copy each of the fields in a separate statement.

car->property1 = my_car.property1

(is my_car a pointer or not? it's impossible to tell from the code fragment)

For the second case, I think you can just assign the entire struct: *car = my_car

Comment: "is my_car a pointer or not? it's impossible to tell from the code fragment": It is declared in another of his code snippets as `static const CarV2`

Answer (score 0):

there is no perfect solution but one way is to use a union

```
typedef union car_union
{
  CarV1 v1;
  CarV2 v2;

} Car;
```

that way the size will not differ when you do a memcpy - if version v1 then v2 specific parts will not be initialized.

Answer (score 0):

In C and Objective-C, this is fine in practice. (In theory, the compiler must see the declaration of a union containing both structs as members).

In C++ (and Objective-C++), the language very carefully describes when this is safe and when it isn't. For example, if you start with

```
typedef struct {
    public: 
    ...
```

then the compiler is free to re-arrange where struct members are. If the struct uses no C++ features then you are safe.